# Unable to establish connection with Pymodbus TCPserver

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, ethernet, modbus, pymodbus

I am setting up a new TCP Server connected to client through an Ethernet TCP/IP modbus and is supposed to push certain values to a given modbus register (hr = 6022), every few seconds. I do not see any exceptions/errors raised by the script but no data is received by the client. With a StartTCPserver command, I expected to see any network traffic (atleast the handshake) but I do not see any traffic on Wireshark. What could be the next possible diagnostic?

I have tried running similar script locally (without an external ethernet connection); One acting as a client and another as a server and did see the values update on the client register.

```py
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
import time
import logging
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
          ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def run_server():
    store = ModbusSlaveContext(
        ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(6022, [152, 276]), 
        zero_mode=True
    )
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
    StartTcpServer(context, address=("192.168.10.2", 502))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Comment: The address on which the server is running and the address at which the client is requesting registers are different. Is that a typo?

Comment: That was a typo. I keep changing the server IP address so, I can avoid error when I attempt to connect multiple times "OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." Not a great way to deal with, but I use this workaround just to get the job done.

Comment: Can you share debug logs for both client and server?

Answer (score 0):

The lines after `run_server()` are never reached. Code connecting to the server can be placed in a different script;

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient     

cli = ModbusClient('192.168.10.2', port=502)                       
assert cli.connect()                                                 
res = cli.read_input_registers(6022, count=1, unit=1)                
print(res.registers[0])
```

Comment: Yes, that's a part of a separate script. I just did't present it very well.

Comment: I did a test with the server code you provided and the client as I posted and did not have any problems.

Comment: Thanks. Since running these client and server programs from separate python terminals doesn't require an Ethernet connection, I tried those too and was able to receive data as I mentioned in the question. However, when I connect to an actual client device (via external Ethernet connection), that's where I am unable to send/receive data. Any ideas what could be wrong. Been stuck for a while now.